# Updating a custom field in a custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types

[`update_post_meta($post_id, 'custom_field_name', 'custom_field_value')`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta) updates a custom field in a post. How to do the same with a custom post type ?

Comment: It really should be the same. Is it not working? Have any example code? A custom post is still just a `post` essentially, and carries values in the `post_meta` table, just like a regular post.

Comment: I realize this function works within the loop only, and the loop already "knows" the type of post involved obviously!

Answer (score 0):

I'd register a 'add_meta_box' to the cpt, the form element will define the custom_field_name and the save action would call update_post_meta.